# How do i remove database data formating when displaying on the front end in python(tkinter)?

Tags: python, ms-access, tkinter

How do i format the data so that it does not display the leading and trailing "(" ")" along with the apostrophes and commas? I'm looking for plain text

```py
conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("select * from cost")
rows = cur.fetchall()
cur.close()
conn.close()
print(rows)
price_list_frame = Frame(root)
price_list_frame.grid(row=0, column=0)
lab1 = Label(root, text="DESCRIPTION HERE")
lab1.grid(row=0, column=2)

tv = ttk.Treeview(price_list_frame, columns=(1, 2, 3), show="headings", height="10")
tv.pack(pady=15)
tv.heading(1, text="ID", anchor='center')
tv.heading(2, text="Product", anchor='center')
tv.heading(3, text="Our Cost", anchor='center')
tv.bind("<<TreeviewSelect>>", lambda e: db_action.get_show_description(tv, lab1))

for i in rows:
    tv.insert('', 'end', values=i)
```

[image: Displays contents of database (treeview)]

Comment: This code looks fine. It seems to me that the problem is with the code that created the database. Looks like someone used `split()` instead of unpacking.

Comment: Try changing `values=i` to `values=[x for x in i]` because `i` is of type `pyodbc.Row`, not a list or tuple.

Comment: [x for x in i] worked perfectly, much appreciated!